# How to correctly use EasyNetQ in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: c#, concurrency, rabbitmq, task-parallel-library, easynetq

I'm learning about message brokers (specifically RabbitMQ) and I've started a project using EasyNetQ. From what I have read, the best practice is to use long-standing connections to the broker and end them at the end of your application. In my project, I am using EasyNetQ in a windows service. Would the best approach be to instantiate the connection (IBus) in the `onStartMethod()` and dispose of it during the `onStop()`? If so, if I instantiate some tasks running on various threads in the `OnStartMethod()` can each thread safely use the Bus instance to publish/subscribe? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all correct, keep one instance of IBus in your app, and it can be safely used from multiple threads.

Comment: Since I am using this instance for the longevity of the app, if I am using the mvvm pattern and I have the Ibus instance in the view model, what is the correct way to dispose of it when the application closes?

Comment: I don't know without some more context. Seems more like a MVVM pattern, not about EasyNetQ, maybe you could post this as a separate question?